# Why does enum field show up as char in PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

I have a MySQL database table called `persons`. This table has two enum fields. In PhpMyAdmin they are enum. However, PhpStorm shows them as char.

Here is an export from PhpMyAdmin:

```
--
-- Database: `underdog`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `persons`
--

CREATE TABLE `persons` (
  `person_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID for each person',
  `username` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(110) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `notetoself` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci COMMENT 'Personal notes of user',
  `is_blocked` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `phptimezone` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'example America/New_York',
  `mobile_phone` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Mobile phone number',
  `country_phonecode` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Prepend for country',
  `membership_level` enum('Platinum','Gold','Silver','Bronze') CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Bronze',
  `realname` varchar(110) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Full name',
  `karma_level` enum('5 Star','4 Star','3 Star','2 Star','1 Star') CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '5 Star',
  `times_blocked` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Number of times this person has been blocked'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `persons`
--
ALTER TABLE `persons`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `mobile_phone` (`mobile_phone`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: PhpStorm version?

Comment: "PhpStorm shows them as char." - What do you mean? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Works just fine in PhpStorm 2016.3.2 & MySQL 5.7.17 on Windows 10 -- http://postimg.org/image/pomyycdah/

Comment: Take a look at the karma_level database field on the right side of the screen shot. It should be of type enum. But it is not.

Comment: Please post code here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers.

Comment: I have the latest version of PhpStorm as of today (Mar 1, 2017).

Comment: Show your data source definition -- `Options` tab -- must be wrong settings. Also -- what MySQL driver do you use (the one that used by PhpStorm)?

Comment: @SamehRamzyLabib Please -- `Options` tab .. not `General`

Comment: @SamehRamzyLabib Post it elsewhere -- just like I did

Comment: I posted the picture for @LazyOne on YouTube: https://youtu.be/yHwzZZ72N8M?list=PL53HNVwgFHMU4gM8zkbZthKGcr2wf-hKs

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed over 1.5 years ago -- [DBE-401](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-401).

Considering that you are using latest 2017.1 EAP version .. this must be due to your current settings.

As per your YouTube video -- please disable `Introspect using JDBC metadata` option at Data Source's `Options` tab.

[image]